# How to provide column definition list for function to returning record from database in wpf using C#?

Tags: c#, wpf

How to provide column definition list for function(stored procedure) to returning record using postgreSQL as a database in wpf using c#?

Example:

Calling Function: In PostgreSQL

```
select * from function1('colmA','tableA') as (name varchar(20), colmA varchar(20), address varchar(20));
```

Note: Same function i would like to call from WPF using C#. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this:

```
string query = string.Format("select * from function1({0},{1}) as (name varchar(20), colmA varchar(20), address varchar(20));", "colmA", tableA);
```

You might want to use SqlParameter-objects to prevent sql injections:

```
string query = "select * from function1(@pa1,@par2); as (name varchar(20), colmA varchar(20), address varchar(20));";
cmd.Parametes.Add("@par1", SqlDbType.String).Value = "colmA";  
cmd.Parametes.Add("@par2", SqlDbType.String).Value = "tableA";
```

i hope this is useful and if you completly new to C# PSQL, i recommend you to read this tutorial:
[Using PostgreSQL in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30989/Using-PostgreSQL-in-your-C-NET-application-An-intr)